# I have a react native app and I want to know how to flag pictures for use in another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an app that cycles through pictures on the press of a button.  I want to add another button that flags a picture when pressed for use in another screen, but I don't know the proper way to do this.

I have a few ideas, but I don't know the proper way to do this and I want to learn.  I am very flexible as far as changing my objects etc.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { type ImageHolder } from './ImageHolder'
import OuterComponent from "./OuterComponent"

const imageholder2: ImageHolder[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    actualimage: require("./images/image1.jpeg"),
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    actualimage: require("./images/image2.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    actualimage: require("./images/image3.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    actualimage: require("./images/image4.jpg"),
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0)
  const scopeSpecificFunction = () =>
  setCurrentImageIndex(currentImageIndex == imageholder2.length - 1 ?
      0 :
      currentImageIndex + 1 )

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {
            imageholder2[currentImageIndex] &&
              <Image
                key={imageholder2[currentImageIndex].id}
                style = {{
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                }}
                source={imageholder2[currentImageIndex].actualimage}
              />
        }
      </View>
      <View>
      <OuterComponent callbackfunction ={()=>scopeSpecificFunction()}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```